# Access shared files in OneDrive for Business with Office 365 client libraries

Tags: .net, office365, onedrive, office365api

Is there a way to access shared files on OneDrive for Business with the Office 365 client libraries? There are many examples on how to access MyFiles, like [this](https://github.com/robledosm/OneDriveForBusiness-Explorer-MVC) great one on github.

The Graph API has access through:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DRIVEID]/items/[FOLDERID]/children
```

I have not found a way to access the same with the SharePointClient, only:

```
var filesResult = await client.Files.ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a C# SDK for OneDrive for Business that you can use to pull user's files.

To get user's drive:

```
var drive = await oneDriveClient
                      .Drive
                      .Request()
                      .GetAsync();
```

To get the root folder files:

```
var rootItem = await oneDriveClient
                             .Drive
                             .Root
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();
```

Here is a GitHub Repo url:

https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, that should do if I can make it run on ASP .NET. Looks like this thread has some issues with that -> https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/45. Ginach from MS says: "Authentication using client secret isn't fully implemented yet." (9 days ago).

Comment: the sdk includes a WinForms sample, but I have not been able to do this in an ASP .NET application.